# rsnapshot settings confusion

Tags: linux, command-line, rsnapshot

I'm trying to set remote backup for my website.
in `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`, I've set the following things but its still not working.

```
snapshot_root   /abc_backups/

backup  root@1.2.3.4:/var/www/abc.com/html/
```

Can anyone help me out on how to set this?

My website server is on `1.2.3.4` and the source is `/var/www/abc.com/html/` and destination is `/abc_backups/`

Comment: "its still not working" - so what's the error message? Please read http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have a `abc_backups` directory at the root of your filesystem? I really doubt it (and even if you did, this is not a good practice). Also `backup` takes 2 arguments, not one as in your example. First the source (what you backup) and then the destination.
Based on your description, change your `backup` line like that:

`backup root@1.2.3.4:/var/www/abc.com/html/ website/`

(which will then backup the website server 1.2.3.4 under `/abc_backups/website/`)

In case of doubts, you can always run `rsnapshot` with the `-t` flag to see what commands it would execute (without executing them really)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes its at the root besides `/var` folder, where should i move it to? `website/` is the folder in the destination server or source server?

Comment: You should avoid creating new directories at the root. For your need, try something under `/var/local` or `/home`. The last argument of `backup` refers to the destination, what you put there would be a subdirectory of your `snapshot_root` directory. This is needed to differentiate between backups from multiple sources.